# Error when getting value of gridrow and adding it to session variable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have an aspx webpage with a grid, which shows several records.

When a row is clicked on, the following code run but I get an error.

The value that is getting is a string, so I am not sure why the error says `string to type double` as I am not trying to convert anything to that.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ??

```
Protected Sub gvProject_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
          Handles gvProject.SelectedIndexChanged 
    Session("PN") = gvProject.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text.ToString
    Session("fromDash1") = gvProject.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text.ToString
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, [GetType](), "none", 
                       "<script> window.open('default2.aspx','_self');</script>", False)
    End Sub
```

Error Message:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Conversion from
>   string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with

```
 Session("PN") =Convert.ToString(gvProject.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text)
 Session("fromDash1") =Convert.ToString(gvProject.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text)
```

Comment: unfortunately same problem.